# Error: ngRepeat:dupes Duplicate Key in Repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a column(I call it in my codebehind as keyW) in a stored procedure that returns this value

```
[{key:138},{key:139},{key:140},{key:141},{key:142},{key:143},{key:145},{key:146},{key:148}]
```

on my design view I have put the code like this

```
<div id="allerg" ng-repeat="allerg in recipe.keyW">
{{allerg.key}}

</div>
```

When I run my page it returns the duplicate key error. I am not sure what is wrong. I am returning the right values as what I have read in the `ng-repeat` documentation

thank you in advance

EDIT: I have also tried the track by `$index`. It removes the error but still doesn't display the values.

Comment: try this ng-repeat="allerg in recipe.keyW track by $index"

Comment: I have tried that, the error goes away but it doesn't display the values

Comment: [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/y4KYUMJu5LyPbGHa0hSG?p=preview) demo and its working problem should be somewhere else...

Comment: is it because recipe.keyW is return as string not as an array?

Comment: ng-repeat needs array to traverse if your object is not array you cannot expect it to work...

Comment: its string like in your plunker but its formatted as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your div ID to something other than allerg

Answer (score -1):

If your array contains int add "track by $index" to your code.

```
<div id="allerg" ng-repeat="allerg in recipe.keyW track by $index">
    {{allerg.key}}
</div>
```